# Is Thread.sleep() a waste of time for polling in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, sleep

Suppose I have a `nametag`, which is UI component in GUI program.
The `nametag` will constantly change its text based on the data.
If the user change his/her name data, then he/she will see the change in `nametag`.

For this task, my code looks like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            String name = data.getName();
            nametag.setText(name);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Since the reaction time of `0.1s` seems instant to people, I included `Thread.sleep(100)` for computer to take a break.

However, I am not sure if that helps the computer in terms of energy usage or something. Is sleep method in this case complete waste of time? No benefit at all?

Comment: Several comments: First, I would rather see you implement some sort of _listener_ which gets called any time there is a _change_ in the name tag, rather than just constantly updating even if there might not be a change.  Second, calling `Thread.sleep` just means the current calling thread yields to any other threads.  If there is another thread waiting, then it won't necessarily save any CPU time.

Comment: If this is a GUI program, you probably need to use some special measures to update UI components from background threads.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `Thread.sleep` will release the CPU for at least the amount indicated, even if there are no other threads wanting to do anything. So it does save CPU compared to a "busy loop".

Comment: Of course its saving CPU time.

Comment: @eldo Perhaps other people don't know that? Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your direct question, but it does help address an XY Problem component of your question:

It looks like you're listening for object state changes by polling: by constantly testing an object to see what its state is and whether it's changed, and this is a bad idea, especially when coding for an *event-driven* GUI. Much better to use an observer pattern and be ***notified*** of state changes when or if they occur. That is how the Swing GUI library itself was written, and you should strongly consider emulating this.

Some ways to be notified of changes are to use component event listeners which can listen for changes to Swing components, such as ActionListeners, ChangeListeners, ItemListeners, and the like. Another way when listening to non Swing component items is to use SwingPropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners and in this way to create "bound" properties of your class. This is often used for non-GUI model classes.

Answer (score 3):

> `Thread.Sleep` has been used for many things it shouldn’t be used for.
>
> Here’s a list of the common mistakes:
>
> **The thread needs to wait for another thread to complete**
>
> In this case no value, other than infinite, passed to `Thread.Sleep` will be correct.  You simply don’t know when the other thread will complete using this method.  If the thread completed after Sleep returned you’ll likely have synchronization problems.  If the other thread completed before Sleep returned the thread was needlessly blocked for an amount of time rendering the benefits of multithreading limited or moot.  In the control circumstances where you’ve tested this it may seem like it always works; it just takes a busy program to cause it to faile: a defrag program, a sudden influx of network traffic, a network hiccup, etc.
>
> **The thread needs perform logic every `n` milliseconds**
>
> As noted earlier, Sleep means relinquish control.  When your thread gets control again isn’t up to the thread; so it can’t be used for periodic logic.
>
> **We don’t know why `Thread.Sleep` is required; but if we take it out the application stops working**
>
> This is flawed logic because the application still doesn’t work with `Thread.Sleep`.  This is really just spackling over the problem on that particular computer.  The original problem is likely a timing/synchronization issue, ignoring it by hiding it with `Thread.Sleep` is only going to delay the problem and make it occur in random, hard to reproduce ways.

Source: http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/

Comment: A `sleep()` call _can_ be used to implement scheduling (e.g., to perform logic every n milliseconds.)  But whether or not it is _accurate enough_ for your application depends on the needs of your application, on the capabilities of the operating system that's hosting it, and maybe on what other applications are doing on the same box.  You don't always need an RTOS to host a real-time application, but the more stringent your real-time requirements, the more it helps.